# Logging the timestamp with tzoffset

Tags: python, logging

I am using python logging module for logging messages. My need is to have following type of date formatter to use in log file. How can I do that?

```
2016-11-29T06:12:59.519908+05:00

Year-Month-DateTHour:Min:Sec.microsec+timezone
```

Currently I am using this

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)06d %(levelname)s %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

which produces following :

```
2017-01-23T01:50:23.000606
```

I am not able to add timezone info.

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is handling milliseconds as it is handled differently when you specify formatting.

we need to subclass `logging.Formatter` to override the `formatTime` method and get the milliseconds from the record.msecs as does the [original `formatTime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L518) function

```
import logging
import time
import pytz
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime


class DateFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%%03d%z'

    def __init__(self, timezone=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timezone = timezone
        super(DateFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(ct) + record.msecs / 1000., self._timezone)
        return dt

r = logging.getLogger()
h = logging.StreamHandler()

timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')
fmt = DateFormatter(timezone, '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
h.setFormatter(fmt)

r.addHandler(h)
r.error('something bad!')
```

this code outputs:

```
2017-01-23 13:45:42.466178+02:00 - root - ERROR - something bad!
```

### Update

another issue is that the logging record does not use `datetime` but `time_struct` which does not have timezone, so on the updated code above I converted the object from `time_struct` to datetime (may cost performance).

The timezone should be provided from outside as the log record does not contains the timezone.

Comment: Missing correct time zone, +0000 is not correct one, output does not match with what I need.